# In Rails 4, how should a controller take a parameter to specify an associate by a non-id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Each Widget has an associated User. Users have a String attribute called `email` which stores the email address associated with the User.

The User model has a unique `id` attribute, as per Rails conventions, but also ensures that `email` addresses are unique. Therefore, `User.where(email: foo@example.com)` is guaranteed to return at most one result.

In a form to create a Widget, I would like users to be able to specify an email address, rather than an ID. Both `id` and `email` are unique keys for Users, but email addresses are more convenient for people.

What's the recommended way for the Widget controller to accept an association reference that names the associate by a key other than `id`? When using `id`, if the `widget[user_id]` parameter stores the ID for a User, mass-assignment (in `create` or `update`) stores the correct User in the Widget. Is there any built-in Rails support for making something like `widget[user_email]` work, or should I add code in the controller to recognize that parameter, look up the User, and associate the User with the Widget?

Here's the code:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class WidgetsController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @widget.save
  end

  def widget_params
    params.require(:widget).permit(...)
  end
end
```

I've considered:

- Modifying the Widget model to add a setter for "user_email", looking up the User there, and setting "user_id" appropriately.
- Modifying WidgetsController#widget_params to notice the presence of "widget[user_email]", look up the User, and replace it with "widget[user_id]".

I'm leaning towards the second option.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding this.  You need to keep the association through the ID if you want this to play with rails.  When you say has_many, belongs_to, has_one, Rails is doing the relationships behind the scenes based on the id fields.  If you want user to associate an email address, you can still pass in the email address, you can then find the user by email address, and associate that record to the widget using the ID.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @fatfrog, thank you for looking at the question. I've made edits to clarify the intent. Your last sentence is where I was heading. I understand the use of ID fields behind-the-scenes; I was just hoping that Rails might have something built-in to handle lookup via alternate keys.

Comment: You can change the foreign key in the relationship like this: has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id" - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html